# "Const" incompatible type qualifier issue/problem in C++

Tags: c++, class, constants, overloading, function-declaration

```
Point Point::add(Point& a,Point& b) {
    Point result {};
    size_t length {std::max(a._vector.size(),b._vector.size())};
    for(size_t i {1};i<=length;++i) {
        result._vector.push_back(a.get(i)+b.get(i));
    }
    return std::move(result);
}
```

The above code works fine, but changing the signature to

```
Point Point::add(const Point& a,const Point& b)
```

gives me **(compile-error)** :

```
E1086   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "Point::get"
object type is: const Point
```

*Note:* `float Point::get(const size_t& component)` does not modify anything.

Kindly help me, please.
Thank you.

Comment: What you don't show in your question is whether `float Point::get(const size_t& component)` is actually `float Point::get(const size_t& component) const`, which it should be if it doesn't change anything, so it can be used on a const object.

Comment: @Supreeto "The above code" can not work fine.:)

Comment: As @stefaanv said, you need to add `const` at the end of `Point::get()` method declaration.

Comment: The question isn't whether a method modifies anything, but whether it is declared `const`

Comment: `const` correctness is one of those things that is easy to get right if done from the get go, but can be quite a bother to clean up in arrears.

Answer (score 1):

The function can not work fine because in this code snippet

```
size_t length {std::max(a._vector.size(),b._vector.size())};
for(size_t i {1};i<=length;++i) {
    result._vector.push_back(a.get(i)+b.get(i));
}
```

there is an access of memory beyond the vectors even if the vectors have the same size.

As for the error message then it is obvious that the member function `get` is not a constant member function and hence may not be called for constant objects.

You need to overload or redeclare the function declared at present like

```
float get(const size_t& component);
```

at least the following way

```
float get(const size_t& component) const;
```

Though it seems declaring the function parameter as having a constant referenced type does not make a great sense. You could declare the function like

```
float get( size_t component ) const;
```

Pay attention to it would be better to overload the function the following way

```
float & get( size_t component );
const float & get( size_t component ) const;
```

Comment: You don't really need to overload the `get` method so it's both `const` and non-`const`. It makes more sense to have just a `const` version; the compiler will use it for `const` and non-`const` objects.